# how can I get np.savetxt to save each iteration of a loop in a different column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, for-loop

This is an extremely basic code that does what I want... except with regard to the writing of the text file.

```
import numpy as np

f = open("..\myfile.txt", 'w')
tst = np.random.random(5)
tst2 = tst/3
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        test = np.random.random(5)+j
        a = np.random.normal(test, tst2)
    np.savetxt(f, np.transpose(a), fmt='%10.2f')
    print a
f.close()
```

This code will write to a .txt file a single column that is concatenated after each iteration of the for loop.

**What I want is independent columns for each iteration.**

**How does one do that?**

note: I have used `np.c_[]` as well, and that *will* write the columns **if** I express each iteration within the command. ie: `np.c_[a[0],a[1]]` and so on. The problem whit this is, what if both my `i` and `j` values are very large? It isn't reasonable to follow this method.

Comment: Demonstrate that last `np.c_[]` bit.  What isn't reasonable about it?

Comment: In the actual code that this small example pertains to, I have 3 nested for loops with a total of 804 iterations, producing with my small sample size a .txt file with 17700 lines. As the sample size increases, the iteration requirement changes in kind. That is why it isn't reasonable.

Comment: Explain the desire file layout in more detail.  How many columns, how many rows?  What's the relation between iteration and columns or row?

Comment: The number of columns is related to the number of iterations, and the number of rows is related to the number of data points sourced. @hpaulj I like your example below of using the np.append feature, however I haven't been able to get it working just yet. Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/q/39010539/3920407] for better example of the code being used.

Answer (score 1):

So a run produces:

```
2218:~/mypy$ python3 stack39114780.py 
[ 4.13312217  4.34823388  4.92073836  4.6214074   4.07212495]
[ 4.39911371  5.15256451  4.97868452  3.97355995  4.96236119]
[ 3.82737975  4.54634489  3.99827574  4.44644041  3.54771411]
2218:~/mypy$ cat myfile.txt
      4.13
      4.35
      4.92
      4.62
      4.07    # end of 1st iteration
      4.40
      5.15
      4.98
      3.97
      ....
```

Do you understand what's going on?  One call to `savetxt` writes a set of lines.  With a 1d array like `a` it prints one number per row.  (`transpose(a)` doesn't do anything).

File writing is done line by line, and can't be rewound to add columns. So to make multiple columns you need to create an array with multiple columns. Then do one `savetxt`.  In other words, collect all the data before writing.

Collect your values in a list, make an array, and write that

```
alist = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        test = np.random.random(5)+j
        a = np.random.normal(test, tst2)
        alist.append(a)
arr = np.array(alist)
print(arr)
np.savetxt('myfile.txt', arr, fmt='%10.2f')
```

I'm getting 15 rows of 5 columns, but you can tweak that.

```
2226:~/mypy$ cat myfile.txt
  0.74       0.60       0.29       0.74       0.62
  1.72       1.62       1.12       1.95       1.13
  2.19       2.55       2.72       2.33       2.65
  3.88       3.82       3.63       3.58       3.48
  4.59       4.16       4.05       4.26       4.39
```

Since `arr` is now 2d, `np.transpose(arr)` does something meaningful - I would get 5 rows with 15 columns.

==================

With

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        test = np.random.random(5)+j
        a = np.random.normal(test, tst2)
    np.savetxt(f, np.transpose(a), fmt='%10.2f')
```

you write `a` once for each `i` - hence the 3 rows.  You throwing away 4 of the `j` iterations.  In my variation I collect all `a`, and hence get 15 rows.

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj's answer first get a 2-D array after all for loops are finished, and then write the entire array to the file. But i guess you might want to write the results to the file during execution.

It's much easier to write results in independent rows than in independent columns while executing a for loop.

In your example, you want to write results of the inner for loop in independent columns, while executing the outer for loop.

Instead you can exchange the outer and inner for loop, store results of the new inner for loop in an array (as hpaulj has pointed out, np.savetxt() only write lines of arrays), and then write this arrays as an independent row.  This is equivalent to saving results of the original inner for loop in independent columns.

To save arrays in independent rows inside the outer for loop, you can use file.write('\n') after numpy.savetxt(...) to separate the rows.  For your original example:

```
for j in range(5): # for loops for i and j are exchanged
    f = open(f'./myfile.txt', 'a') # create a new file, or add sth to an existing file
    a = [] # store results of the new inner for loop in an 1-D array
    for i in range(3):
        test = np.random.random(5)+j
        a.append(np.random.normal(test, tst2))
    np.savetxt(f, np.array(a).transpose(), newline=' ') # Write the array as a new row in the text file
    f.write('\n') # jump to a new line
    f.close()
```